# I Can't spawn buttons in my Grid. why?

Tags: unity, grid, instancing

Today i was following a tutorial about making a shop, but i got a problem.

[image: There's the getItemButton, the Grid with the scrollbar(scrollbar is hiddden inside the red box), and the button inside of it.]

and i've followed the scripting tutorial, but it seems i can't spawn a button inside the grid when i pressed GetItemButton. here's how the script goes:

```
public class ItemCatalogue : MonoBehaviour {

public Items[] AvailableItems;
public Text DisplayArray;

public void GetItem() {
   Items item = AvailableItems[Random.Range(0, AvailableItems.Length)];
    InventoryCatalogue.Instance.AddMaterialToCatalogue(new ItemStack(item, 1));
    DisplayArray.text = item.name;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    }
}
```

and another one:

```
public class InventoryCatalogue : MonoBehaviour {

public static InventoryCatalogue Instance;

public List<ItemStack> MatStorage;

public Transform ScrollList;
public GameObject ItemPrefab;

void Start()
{
    if (Instance != null) {
        return;
    }
    Instance = this;
    MatStorage = new List<ItemStack>();
}


public void AddMaterialToCatalogue(ItemStack Stack) {
    bool hasItem = false;
    foreach (ItemStack i in MatStorage) {
        if (i.item.name == Stack.item.name) {
            hasItem = true;
            i.amount += Stack.amount;
        }
    }
    if (!hasItem) {
        MatStorage.Add(Stack);
    }
  }
}
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: What is the expected sequence of events when this code is working properly? What sequence of events do you observe instead? Have you used breakpoints or debug logging to check each step of your code and find out where it departs from your expected behaviour?

Comment: i was expecting that i will add another blank button to the grid in the redbox each time i press the GetButton Item

Comment: Are you using the grid layout? What's the setup for your grid? Unity layout groups are finicky and lie to you sometimes (content fitters, size options, etc). I have a lot of experience with the UI system so if you're using that I can tell you the setup for a flexible, scalable grid. If not, then it's harder to pinpoint the problem

Comment: X Y Cell size: 80 100,
both spacing 5,
Start Corner left,
Start Axis Horizontal,
Child Alignment Upper Left,
Constraint Flexible,